# Running a task in Ansible if there was any error during the playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a huge playbook with a lot of tasks in it:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - mario-configuration.yml

  post_tasks:
    # After the playbook run, tell it's over
    - name: It's a me, Mario!
      shell: 'say -v Luca "Itsami, Mario!"'

  roles:
    - aerial        # installs appletv like screen saver: https://aerialscreensaver.github.io
    - clean-dock    # remove all the stickies in the macOS dock, useful after a fresh install
    - clean-desktop # hides the files in the desktop (they are still there, just hidden)
    - rocket        # emoji picker: https://matthewpalmer.net/rocket
    # ... more roles
    - vlc           # video viewer: https://www.videolan.org/vlc
```

(whole code is open-sourced here: https://github.com/web-id-fr/mario)

This build is running in MacOS, and at the end of it I run the "say" command to tell the user it ended. But if there is an error during the playbook the `post_tasks` is not run. Is there a simple way in Ansible to run a specific task if any role has failed?

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16437) for that kind of thing.

Comment: thanks @papanito I've added a comment there as well 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is not possible (yet) as stated in [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

> When Ansible receives a non-zero return code from a command or a failure from a module, by default it stops executing on that host and continues on other hosts.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16437) for that kind of thing.